# UIView drawRect issue

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect

I want to make custom UIView with border. Here is my code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextAddRect(context, self.frame);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

And here is the result: [image]

All three UIView on this picture is my custom view, but only big UIView have the border. I don't understand why others have no border. What is wrong?

Comment: Did all the `UIView` are of same custom class?

Comment: Please show some code?

Comment: I make it via storyboard. I don't have more code, just custom class with this drawRect method

Comment: Don't know what is happened but You've missed `[super drawRect:rect];`

Comment: Mani, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15387059/2803425

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need local coordinates. Change

```
CGContextAddRect(context, self.frame);
```

to

```
CGContextAddRect(context, self.bounds);
```

Comment: If my answer solves the question, please accept it. Someone can find this post searching solution for similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't specify the classname for subviews
2. why don't you try like this

   ```
   anyView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
   anyView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
   ```
3. Or add this method in your custom view

   ```
   -(void)awakeFromNib{

       [super awakeFromNib];

       self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
       self.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;

   }
   ```

Comment: What do you mean - You didn't specify the classname for subviews? 
I named it BorderedView and specify class name for all UIViews in storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for 2 and 3, but I need also make not full border - without upper line, for example.

Comment: add white plain view on top of your view, which will hide that border if you needed

Comment: It will be tableViewCell, not just view. So that's not the way.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have not added the `path` to your context

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, NULL);
    [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

Comment: CGContextAddRect draws without path http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Graphics_Tutorial_using_Core_Graphics_and_Core_Image

Comment: I have provided the answer which I use generally. and you have missed the point `CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80);`. check that

Comment: I've used self.frame (should use self.bounds, but now it does not matter). So CGRectMake is needless.

Comment: You don't need call super in this method too stackoverflow.com/a/15387059/2803425

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
The problem was in self.frame for CGContextAddRect. It must be self.bounds to draw in my view.